# Angular + d3 + Json data

Tags: angularjs, json, d3.js

I'm trying to build a simple visualization using d3 and angular. The viz should be based on JSON data from a DashDB request. I cannot achieve the result but I don't know why. I started from an example that use data hard coded in javascript : https://www.sitepoint.com/creating-charting-directives-using-angularjs-d3-js/. I would like dashdb requested data instead.
Here is my code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>AngularJS + D3.js</title>
    <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.1/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="app.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div ng-app="chartApp" ng-controller="tempController">
        <h1>Today's temperatures</h1>
        <div linear-chart chart-data="tempData"></div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Javascript :

```
var app = angular.module('chartApp', []);
app.controller('tempController', ['$scope', function($scope){
d3.json('https://mynoderedstarter.eu-gb.mybluemix.net/test1', function(err, temps){
    if(err) throw err;

        $scope.tempData = temps;

});
}]);

app.directive('linearChart', function($window){
   return{
  restrict:'EA',
  template:"<svg width='850' height='200'></svg>",
   link: function(scope, elem, attrs){
       console.log(scope.tempData);
       var tempDataToPlot=scope[attrs.chartData];
       var padding = 20;
       var pathClass="path";
       var xScale, yScale, xAxisGen, yAxisGen, lineFun;

       var d3 = $window.d3;
       var rawSvg=elem.find('svg');
       var svg = d3.select(rawSvg[0]);

       function setChartParameters(){

           xScale = d3.scale.linear()
               .domain([tempDataToPlot[0].HOURS, tempDataToPlot[tempDataToPlot.length-1].HOURS])
               .range([padding + 5, rawSvg.attr("width") - padding]);

           yScale = d3.scale.linear()
               .domain([0, d3.max(tempDataToPlot, function (d) {
                   return d.TEMP;
               })])
               .range([rawSvg.attr("height") - padding, 0]);

           xAxisGen = d3.svg.axis()
               .scale(xScale)
               .orient("bottom")
               .ticks(tempDataToPlot.length - 1);

           yAxisGen = d3.svg.axis()
               .scale(yScale)
               .orient("left")
               .ticks(5);

           lineFun = d3.svg.line()
               .x(function (d) {
                   return xScale(d.HOURS);
               })
               .y(function (d) {
                   return yScale(d.TEMP);
               })
               .interpolate("basis");
       }

     function drawLineChart() {

           setChartParameters();

           svg.append("svg:g")
               .attr("class", "x axis")
               .attr("transform", "translate(0,180)")
               .call(xAxisGen);

           svg.append("svg:g")
               .attr("class", "y axis")
               .attr("transform", "translate(20,0)")
               .call(yAxisGen);

           svg.append("svg:path")
               .attr({
                   d: lineFun(tempDataToPlot),
                   "stroke": "blue",
                   "stroke-width": 2,
                   "fill": "none",
                   "class": pathClass
               });
       }

       drawLineChart();
   }
   };
});
```

There is no result at all (nothing displayed). I got this error in console :
    Error: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'tempDataToPlot[0]')

scope.tempData is undefined but scope contain a tempData object well populated with an array containing my data.

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: What is the result? Can you describe the problem behavior you are seeing?

Comment: There is no result at all. I got this error in console : Error: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'tempDataToPlot[0]'). If I log scope.tempData it is undefined. But if I log scope only, I can see the property tempData well populated with an array containing my data.

Comment: is $scope.tempData being defined in the d3 response? therefore not accessible in the app.directive. Either including the app.directive function in the d3.json function or making $scope a global variable would be my guess.

Comment: You're probably right. It seems that d3.json is made to treat result directly in the callback function. I don't know if it is possible to make result visible outside of it. I tried to put the app.directive in the callback function but angular won't start then....I think I have to consider other solution than d3.json function to get data.